# How to import flutter (not dart) collections library?

Tags: flutter

I'm able to import

```
import 'dart:collection';
```

But that's not the same as the library with an API here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/package-collection_collection-library.html

I can't seem to figure out the correct uri for import this library, and can't find any thing on the web or the api about this.

Comment: You do not need to indicate that you are going to respond to yourself.

Comment: Good to know. I had seen this done by someone with a lot more rep than me, and thought maybe it was a courtesy to those who are trying to find people who are needing answers. Sometimes people do write half-baked answers without reading the answer I've already written, which is slightly annoying.

Comment: 1) If it is not strictly necessary then it is only noise, what practical advantage does it have to point it out? Well, nothing, here we are interested in the Q&A, not the authors of the Q&A. 2) Any answer in itself is good, an answer is that valid attempt to solve the OP's problem, these answers can be partial, total or negative (indicate that there is no solution). If you consider an answer to be bad then give it a DV. 3) Only the questions that they do not try to answer such as spam, insults, etc. should be eliminated. Please read [ask] and [answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Comment: Note: if your pubspec does not explicitly include this package, it won't appear in quick-fixes/autocompletion even though flutter depends on it.

Comment: Does your Dart project have a pubspec.yaml file to configure the imports?